# Redis: Dump db and delete dumped key / value pairs

Tags: redis

I have multiple servers that all store set members in a shared Redis cache. When the cache fills up, I need to persist the data to disk to free up RAM. I then plan to parse the dumped data such that I will be able to combine all of the values that belong to a given key in MongoDB.

My first plan was to have each server process attempt an `sadd` operation. If the request fails because Redis has reached `maxmemory`, I planned to query for each of my set keys, and write each to disk.

However, I am wondering if there is a way to use one of the inbuilt persistence methods in Redis to write the Redis data to disk and delete the key/value pairs after writing. If this is possible I could just parse the rdb dump and work with the data in that fashion. I'd be grateful for any help others can offer on this question.

Comment: It sounds like your use of Redis is an antipattern. It's not meant to be a reliable persistent store. So inferring that losing some objects to server failure must be okay, you should consider registering for pubsub notifications. https://redis.io/topics/notifications They're not currently guaranteed delivery, but they're basically no more unreliable than what you currently plan.

Comment: @Gene I'm just using Redis to accumulate data that I eventually write to disk. This is just to aggregate write operations in a distributed computing environment. I don't mind missing some operations, and because all of my data types are sets, duplicate writes to disk are only wasteful, not fatal. Does this still sound like an antipattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis' persistence is meant to be used for whatever's in the RAM. Put differently, you can't persist what ain't in RAM.

To answer your question: no, you can't use persistence to "offload" data from RAM.

Comment: what about a Lua script that atomically ran a save then flushall -- my hunch is that would outperform my current approach, which is to query for all keys, then persist and delete each atomically...